# Non-toxic organic bases?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, toxicity

I am trying to find out if there are any non-toxic organic bases that could be given orally on a non-empty stomach to treat acidosis. From my research, histidine and diluted choline hydroxide were the best candidates. Some phosphazenes, including polyphosphazenes, could make the cut, but I don't know which ones exactly.

Wikipedia [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_base) lists the following compounds as organic bases: pyridine, alkanamines (such as methylamine), imidazole, benzimidazole, histidine, guanidine, phosphazene bases, hydroxides of quaternary ammonium cations or some other organic cations.

The LDLO of guanidine given orally to rabbits is 500 mg/kg [[2]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2e0a/1e862534e373db54433d988e9fe88391c168.pdf). The LD50 of imidazole (rabbits, oral) is 950 mg/kg. Pyridine seems to be in the same range [[3]](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/article-abstract/549079). Benzimidazoles are also toxic.

Histidine, which is considered the most toxic amino acid, can be therapeutic in doses of up to 4.5 g/d, but is toxic in the range 24–64 [[4]](https://academic.oup.com/jn/article/134/6/1633S/4688868).

The last ones from this list are choline hydroxide and phosphazenes. The UTL of choline is 3.5 g/d; in the 10-16 g/d range it causes fishy smell so it probably overloads us with TMA, which is a carcinogen. Polyphosphazenes are being studied for drug delivery; apparently their metabolism generates low-toxicity products such as urea and phosphates. [[5]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3982046/).

Comment: Well, that's quite some research, still -1 from me - it's clearly too broad, also not realistic. Everything is "toxic" if dose is too high. This paragraph about histidine in particular shows that it would be all too good already - "toxic" when at least 24 g is eaten? Maybe water is also too toxic for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naturally occuring amino acid with basic sidechain - L-Arginine:

> Oral supplementation with L-arginine at doses up to 15 grams daily are generally well tolerated.

[source here](https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00125)

Comment: Yes,  I am upgrading as this is an excellent answer as it is non-toxic and has associated health benefits. Some may be aware that Al(OH)3 was once viewed as a non-toxic treatment for excess acid, but more research suggests, based on the interaction of the superoxide radical anion with Al3+, it is probably not a good idea to have those Aluminum ions running around in ones body.